# Can't understand an equality between sums

Tags: summation, combinations

During an induction proof I came across an equality that I can't understand.
During the last step of the induction there is:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}{(k+1){n \choose k-1}} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{(k+2){n \choose k}} $$

My question is which sum and combination   identities were used to achieve this transformation. Using simply the index shift of sums I couldn't work out the same result.
Edit: I understand that the equality stands, I can't understand how I can produce the RHS from the LHS. Which identities do I have to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're unfamiliar with index shifts, change the variable first.
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n} (k+1)\binom{n}{k-1}
&=\sum_{h=1}^{n} (h+1)\binom{n}{h-1} && \text{(change dummy variable)} \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (k+2)\binom{n}{k} && 
  \begin{gathered}
  h-1=k \\
  h+1=k+2 \\
  \begin{aligned}
  & h=1\implies k=0\\
  & h=n\implies k=n-1
  \end{aligned}
  \end{gathered}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Just write down the terms explicitly on both sides. The term corresponding to $k=1$ on LHS is same as the one corresponding to $k=0$ on RHS. The two sides are sums of exactly the same numbers.

Comment: Thank your for the answer. I understand how these two are equal, I can't understand the way I could, for example, reproduce the RHS from the LHS

Comment: Put $k=j+1$ in LHS. You will get exactly RHS but with $j$ in place of $k$. But variables of summation are 'dummy' variables. The value of the sum does not depend on what symbol you use for them. So you can switch $j$ to $k$ at the end.

Comment: If I just use the substitution $k=j+1$ how does the upper limit of the sum change from $n to n-1$ ?

Comment: When $k=n$ the value of $j$ is $k-1=n-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that$$\sum_{k=1}^n(k+1)\binom n{k-1}=2\binom n0+3\binom n1+\cdots+(n+1)\binom nn$$and that$$\sum_{k=0}^n(k+2)\binom nk=2\binom n0+3\binom n1+\cdots+(n+1)\binom nn.$$So, you are summing the *same* numbers!